# How to give icon filter for size and colours in php

Tags: php, html, css, filter, imagefilter

I have developed a website which has filters for product sorting and filtration.
So it comes as rows of values with check boxes on it.

Here is an image of what it looks like now:
[image]

I want it to look as same as it is here (sample from flipkart).
[image]

Here is my code
So please let me know how can I make it to image icon

```
<section  class="sky-form">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus colit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#neck"></span>
                                    <b style="font-size:1em">Neck type</b>
                                    <div class="row row1 scroll-pane collapse in" id="neck" style="width:100%">
                                        <?php foreach($r5 as $k5 => $v5){  ?>                     
                                        <div class="col col-4">
                                            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="neck" value="<?php echo $r5[$k5]["data"];?>" <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['filarr'])){ if(in_array($r5[$k5]["data"] ,$_SESSION['filarr'])){ echo "checked";} } ?>><i></i><?php echo $r5[$k5]["data"]; ?></label>
                                        </div> 
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </section>

                                <section  class="sky-form">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus colit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#color"></span>
                                    <b style="font-size:1em">Colour</b>
                                    <div class="row row1 scroll-pane collapse in" id="color" style="width:100%">
                                        <?php foreach($r6 as $k6 => $v6){    ?>                   
                                        <div class="col col-4">
                                            <label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="colour" value="<?php echo $r6[$k6]["data"];?>"  <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['filarr'])){ if(in_array($r6[$k6]["data"] ,$_SESSION['filarr'])){ echo "checked";} } ?>><i></i><?php echo $r6[$k6]["data"];?></label>
                                        </div> 
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </section>
```

Comment: Can you post your css where you have tried to do this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking...

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox looks change depending on browser and OS used. There is't much you can do to change that. Only solution is to switch them with JavaScript checkboxes, something like http://icheck.fronteed.com/